# Unable to set the default value for drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

In my application one drop down list is there, in which the values are coming dynamically from database. If I select any category value in drop down list and go for menu and If I reset the database I need to clear the select value of drop down and set the default value "Select Category". But I am unable to clear the selected value of the drop down list.

My code is as follows,

Script:

```
<script>
    function resetconformation()
    {
        var x;
        var r=confirm("Do you want to reset database!");
        if (r==true)
        {
        var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
         db.transaction(function (tx) {
                           tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Locationlog');
                           });
        //$('#select-choice option:contains("Select Category")').prop('selected',true);
        $("#select-choice").empty();
        $("#locationList").empty();
        $("#maillocation").hide();
        var optionheading = '<option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>';
        $("#select-choice").append(optionheading);
        $("#select-choice").refresh();
        $('#select-choice option:contains("Select Category")').prop('selected',true);
        $('#select-choice option[value="Select Category"]').attr('selected',true);

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select name="select-choice" id="select-choice" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" style="width:230px">
```

Select Category

How can I set the default value "Select Category" after reset the database? Any suggestions..

Comment: seems to be [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/tN56D/)

Comment: But please cache the object or chain the statements

Comment: Yes, but not in my application. I am using side panel for menu list. Reset database is one option in it. on click of reset database it will show an alert box. on click of yes I am reseting the db.

Comment: How can I do the cache the object or chain the statements?

Comment: unless you've added custom jquery function. `$("#select-choice").refresh();` will throw error.. everything else seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/tN56D/1/

You are missing one bug line:

```
$("#select-choice").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Every dynamically added content must be enhanced manually, jQuery Mobile will not do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
var sel = $("#select-choice").get(0); // get the DOM object
sel.options.length=1; // no need to delete all and add the Select Category each time
sel.selectedIndex=0;
```